# Outlook 2007 rendering problems - print & forward function

Tags: html, outlook, outlook-2007

we have noticed that the template we created for a client causes some problems in Outlook 2007. If you press the forward or print button in Outlook, it takes approx. 2 minutes for Outlook to take this order. We presume that there is a specific html coding that causes a longer rendering time. Could you please have a look at the code? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

http://www.mail-images.com/outlook_performance/sourcecode_newsletter.html

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of nesting errors, that needs to be rechecked.

For example, you have in your code things like:

```
<font><a>Text here</font></a>
```

While it should be

```
<a><font>Text here</font></a>
```

Another thing, try to reduce as much as possible the amount of nested tables. Like, don't nest a one cell table inside another one, that would just slow the rendering.